# Difference between 换钱 and 挽钱

Tags: meaning, difference

My take is that 挽钱 (wǎn qián ) would mean to withdraw money from an ATM and 换钱 (huàn qián) to change money
... or am I mistaken?a

Comment: 挽钱 is just misspelling (actually I shouldn't say misspelling because chinese words are not spelled. but you know what i mean. ;) )

Comment: `挽钱`: Never heard of that.

Answer (score 6):

No such saying as '挽钱'. It's not even a word.

'换钱' means exchanging money.

When you are going to withdraw money from an ATM, a Chinese usually says '取(qu3)钱'.

Comment: Good to know , I picked that up from some online studying list... thankk for Your help

Comment: U r welcome. You can always ask me for help. That online studying list must be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

挽钱 might be a typo?
挽 can be used in the context of walking hand in hand (挽手), or deterring (挽留 - although this can be used in a positive context, like if you don't want your friend to leave). It can also mean resuscitation (挽救)